# Display specific posts with custom meta data wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am building a video sharing website. each video/post has specific post meta of quality.. either it is hd or sd.. how to show only hd videos/posts?

I want to show only posts that has meta data quality=hd.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: How are you storing the video data and meta data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
        "post_type" => "-=your custom post type==-",
        "meta_query" => array (
            array (
              "key" => "quality",
              "value" => "hd",
              "compare" => "IN"
            )
          ) 
    );
$result = new WP_Query($args);
```

I use that code to grab results with a certain key.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same thing with the url. for example
www.example.com/?post_type=post&meta_key=quality&meta_key=hd

Comment: BillyB is there any way to do the same thing with URL?